# bootstrap popover html class lost

Tags: jquery, class, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have this bootstrap popover:

```
$(function(){
    $('#example').popover({
        placement: 'bottom', 
        html: true, 
        content: $('#side').html()
    });
});
```

Which takes its content code from the div:

```
<div id="side">
    <a href="#" class="song1">SummerShe</a><br/>
    <a href="#" class="song2">Funeral Beaver</a>    
</div>
```

The problem is that when I click links on the popover nothing happens, I think the classes song1 and song2 are not transmitted to the popover.

(The classes works just fine If I click links on the div id="side", so this is clearly a problem with a popover.)

Comment: My guess is that you have click handlers bound to the links? If not, my answer is not really relevant.

Comment: Try changing that `html()` to a `clone()`

Answer (score -1):

You are essentially creating a shallow clone of the content inside of `#side`. When doing shallow clones data and event handlers are not copied over, which is why clicking the links does nothing. Instead, create a [deep clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) that also copies data and event handlers:

```
$(function(){
    $('#example').popover({
        placement: 'bottom', 
        html: true, 
        content: $('#side').children().clone(true);
    });
});
```

If you aren't using the links inside of `#side`, it's better to just append them directly to the popover once it opens, but I guess there's a reason you aren't doing that already.